# Android: Transfer a little bit of data between classes within an app

Tags: android, android-intent, data-transfer

How to transfer small amounts of data between classes (activities or services) within an app, using intents.
There are differences between activities and services that need to be clearly shown. Information is scattered in many pieces, in many different answers. Many answers give incorrect information for services.

Answer (score 1):

With small amounts of data, an intent can be used to carry data from one class to another. Here i try to show the basic principle in one place. You can build more complexity into your intents as you want.

SENDING: from both an activity or service class. The Key Name can be anything you want. It must be in quotes. It is the only thing referred to in the receiving class. Also, you may use "this" or "context" instead of "getApplicationContext()", depending on your situation.

```
    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ClassName.class);
    i.putExtra("AnyKeyName1", intName1);  // an int value, no quotes
    i.putExtra("AnyKeyName2", "String Value 1");  // string in quotes
    i.putExtra("AnyKeyName3", StringVariable1);  // string variable, no quotes
    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);  // other additions
    startService(i);
```

RECEIVING IS DIFFERENT IN ACTIVITY AND SERVICE CLASSES.

RECEIVING IN AN ACTIVITY:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
    int var1 = getIntent().getIntExtra("AnyKeyName1");
    String var2 = getIntent().getStringExtra("AnyKeyName2");
    String var3 = getIntent().getStringExtra("AnyKeyName3");
```

RECEIVING IN A SERVICE: You cannot use "getIntent()". You must provide a default value - set it to the value that you want if the intent doesnt receive anything - theres a lot of flexibility with the default values.

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    int var1 = intent.getIntExtra("AnyKeyName1", defaultInt);
    String var2 = intent.getStringExtra("AnyKeyName2", "default String");
    String var3 = intent.getStringExtra("AnyKeyName3", defaultStringVar);
```